# What is a number? Is human's cognition sense allowed us to know numbers?

Tags: numbers, cognition

I know number is an abstract object. But I am not satisfied. Let's take number 1 represents any wholesome unit that we consider, say a goat .Then we say number 2 as 2 of that wholesome unit, here 2 goats. My question is how we came to know number 2 as it's definition itself containing number 2 in any other forms like couple, pair etc... ?

My question is so deep and I think I didn't properly expressed in terms of words. Please understand my question.

Comment: We do not "know numbers"; we learn how to use number words when we learn the activity of *counting*.

Comment: Here is a goat. And here is another goat. This does not invoke the concept of 2, and can be used to introduce it. Notationally, a a does not use 2 even though it is 2 a-s.